# Assigning data template to list box at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my xaml code, inside the `Window.Resources` section, I have defined a Data Template with a `x:key`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:key>
     ...
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have a list box to which I have to assign this data template inside the .xaml.cs code. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the window's code-behind, you can do this:

```
myListBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["resourceKey"];
```

Unless you have a reason to use code-behind, I would stick to XAML and use @Charleh's approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemTemplate to assign a data template to each item in the list declaratively in XAML

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource YourResourceKey}">
```

assuming your DataTemplate is called YourResourceKey

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="YourResourceKey">
```

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah I'd stay away from code-behind approach - is there a reason you need to do it in code-behind?